# Townhall meeting now that we've graduated

Tags: discussion, townhall

Now that we've graduated, there are several things some of us have mentioned as wanting to get nailed down, changed or debated.

For example - how to handle subjective questions, what the slogan is, thoughts on the blog for the site, and so on.

I propose the following, which I volunteer to take care of.

**Step 1** - a vote on the best date and time for the townhall.

**Step 2** - I'll schedule a meeting in the chat room for this time.

**Step 2.5** - Topics for the townhall suggested.

**Step 3** - I'll create a survey page for the topics to be discussed. These can be voted on.

**Step 4** - We'll spend 5-10 minutes (a timer will be set) on each topic for the duration of the meeting, which I hope won't exceed an hour.  Hopefully less.

I realise the casual user of this site won't care, but those of us who have been here since the beginning have noticed the arrival of a lot of new questions of dubious quality since the graduation, so before we get too big we'd like to discuss changing our informal rules/policies on handling new questions, among other things.

Anyway...

**STEP 1** - choosing a date/time.  This is not going to be easy, given all the timezones.  Therefore, what I'll suggest doing is:
 - suggest a time in UTC that best suits you.
 - if possible, suggest a date too.
 - others can vote on that.
 - I'll select the most picked one, and move on to Step 2 and 3.

**UPDATE** - [Register now for the Townhall meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule) on 31st Jan at 22:00 UTC.

Comment: Note - date chosen should be in the 1st week of February, to give some bounds to the exercise.

Comment: An option to suggest meeting topics would be appreciated.

Comment: Ah my shifts for February have not yet been posted so there's no way for me to know when I'd be available then. I do know I'm available for the three days from tomorrow.

Comment: @mindcorrosive - thanks, for some reason I missed that step. Now step 2.5. :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every workday UTC 21:00 - 24:00 is okay for me.

### Available

- todofixthis (after 1 February)
- RoflcoptrException
- mindcorrosive
- Rory Alsop
- Kate Gregory
- HaLaBi
- Dirty-flow
- Stuart
- Jonas
- Ankur Banerjee

### Unavailable

- hippietrail (at least on Jan 31, Feb 1, Feb 2)

Comment: Note to voters: if you vote for it, please edit the answer and put your name in, to indicate who voted for it (so we know who can come)

Comment: barring exceptions, these should all work for me too. After midnight I should still be okay, but my level of alertness will tail off....

Comment: gah, these are the hours I'm at work in the afternoon in Vancouver :/  I'll have to see what my schedule is like.

Comment: And you all can be there? :)  If the time slot is this popular, we may have to go for it, but someone may need to volunteer to moderate (ie keep things on topic) as I'll possibly be indisposed.

Comment: @MarkMayo: on the internet, nobody knows you are naked in front of the computer :-) no need to put on a tie and shirt.

Comment: By indisposed I mean at work. I assure you, I'm not naked at work :)

Comment: Just make sure you guys leave your webcams turned off.

Comment: I am going to be in transit from Mendoza, Argentina to Asunción, Paraguay via bus (thanks to everyone who contributed to [Land transportation between Asunción, Paraguay and Santiago Chile](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/10181/82)!).  I'm estimating that it will take about 30 hours, so I will probably not have any internet access for a couple of days.

Comment: @ankur-banerjee - are you able to be there? I can't guarantee that I can get into it during that time (being at work), so it'd help if there was a mod around to keep things on track.

Comment: @vmatm - are you able to be there? I can't guarantee that I can get into it during that time (being at work), so it'd help if there was a mod around to keep things on track.

Comment: [Register now for the Townhall meeting](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule)

Comment: As usual with my kooky work schedule, even though I only get 2 or 3 shifts per week at the moment, I won't be able to make this one. I'll be running the morning shift and it starts at check out time here - usually our busiest hour of the day ...

Answer (score 0):

Feb 6th at 01:30(UTC) also works well for me.

- Dirty-flow

Comment: Note to voters: if you vote for it, please edit the answer and put your name in, to indicate who voted for it (so we know who can come)

Answer (score 0):

All times are UTC.

Any week day between 10:30-18:00 bar Tuesdays.

the following days between 20:00 - 24:00 :
31/1/2013, 7/2/2013, 11/2/2013, and 13/2/2013

Any week day between Midnight and 02:30 I'm a 70% chance.

Comment: You may as well add your name to the 21-24 answer above, it matches most of your evening times.  I think it's looking like the 31st at this rate.

Answer (score -1):

Feb 5th at 01:00(UTC) is my best bet, as it gives me a chance to get out of work in time for it.

### Available

- todofixthis
- HaLaBi

Comment: Note to voters: if you vote for it, please edit the answer and put your name in, to indicate who voted for it (so we know who can come)

Answer (score -1):

Any time within 72 hours (3 days) of Jan 28th 10:00(UTC) works for me.
<sup>(For February I haven't yet been told my shifts.)</sup>

Comment: Note to voters: if you vote for it, please edit the answer and put your name in, to indicate who voted for it (so we know who can come)