# Townhall meeting Feb 2013 -- agenda

Tags: discussion, townhall

**[Please sign up now for the townhall event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule)**

Here's the place to suggest topics for inclusion in the agenda of [the upcoming Townhall meeting](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/townhall-meeting-now-that-weve-graduated). Add your suggestion as a separate answer, optionally provide some context or description. Vote up on the suggestions you'd like to be discussed.

An arbitrary threshold should probably be set -- to keep the schedule tight, let's say the top 5 rated answers by 12pm, Jan 30 (UTC).  **The meeting takes place on Jan 31, 22:00-23:00 UTC**.

If you don't like a topic, or don't feel it should be discussed, please downvote it.

**EDIT ----- THANKS FOR VOTING!**

**[Please sign up now for the townhall event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule)**

The Agenda, 10 minutes open discussion on each of 5 topics.  Please don't go past the 10 minutes and stay on topic.

**TOPICS and TIMES (all times are UTC)**

- (1 minute to allow latecomers)
- *22:01-22:10* - SE staff have asked for suggested blogs, sites to advertise on, thoughts? Do we do sponsored posts, straight adverts or what?
- *22:11-22:20* - we've been traditionally lenient in the first 24 hours of a new post to give people a chance to improve them.  Now that we've graduated, the proposal is if a question is at all not suitable, close-vote (with comments to help them) and the questioner can always edit and flag to reopen later.  Thoughts?
- *22:21-22:30* - The blog - consensus is we going to have one, so who is going to run it, and what content should be on it? How often should it update?
- *22:31-22:40* - How to handle naming conventions, tags and the like (eg Myanmar/Burma)
- *22:41-22:50* - Ideas for community growth - outside of the official advertising aspect - what can we do?
- *22:51-23:00* (or later) - open discussion of any topic

**[Please sign up now for the townhall event](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/591/you-are-here?tab=schedule)**

Answer (score 8):

There's apparently an advertising budget, SE staff have mentioned, vote for this answer if you'd like to discuss where we could suggest we advertise (specific blogs, websites etc)

Answer (score 8):

How to handle naming conventions, tags and the like (eg Myanmar/Burma)

Comment: You want to cover this in *5* minutes and still be meaningful??

Comment: I suppose if the outcome of the discussion is that it needs more discussion, we can always have another single-topic meeting for those that care :)

Answer (score 7):

Should we give new questions a period of leniency to allow them to edit/improve after we've commented, or just close, and they can flag for reopening if they improve them?

Answer (score 6):

The site's logo - do we like it, should we change it, and if so, how do we decide?

Comment: Related: Site brand name. Currently it says "Travel answers", which is as generic as it would get. Other SE sites have this -- for example, see [Cooking-SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/) and [Gaming-SE](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @mindcorrosive Good point, if this is selected, it'll include the name.

Comment: If the argument that a generic travel-related logo is bad, why would a generic name be good? And conversely, if we must have a generic name, then why not the generic pushpin+compass that's so popular?

Answer (score 6):

The blog - are we going to have one, who is going to run it, and what content should be on it?

Comment: Yes and you're going to run it, as discussed months ago d-;

Comment: :-) I'm happy to write up the odd blog post, if ones about out of the way islands are of interest (Falklands, Foula, Orkney etc) - and I have a bit of experience running the Security.SE blog

Comment: I'd be interested in contributing articles as well.  Not to start the discussion early, but it doesn't have to be just one person posting articles, right?  (:

Comment: @todofixthis: no, it's usually a group of at least 3-4 people that need to step up for the blog to be created. A post every month or so per user should be quite all right. 'sides, a blog is a useful venue for announcements etc. that won't require travelling :-) MSO and blog.SE should turn more information on how this is set up etc.

Comment: I'd love to contribute in some way or other. The problem is I'm much better bouncing ideas around in a conversation than sitting down and writing assays. In fact I flunked English class more than once because of this! `\-:`

Answer (score 6):

Ideas for community growth - outside of the official advertising aspect - so what can **we** do?

Comment: Actually for at least this couple of weeks I bet we'll be growing pretty fast compared to what we're used to. We'll have to learn how to deal with more newbie traffic faster. After we get used to that if we can handle it well it would then be time to push growth I think.

Comment: That's a good point as well, @hippie

Answer (score 3):

Discussion on recommendation and shopping questions

Comment: Was this not settled in http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/806/82 ?

Comment: Evidently not, people are still answering questions like this, so I thought it might be worth raising.  But we'll see what people vote for.

Comment: After being active here for what, a year and a half, I'm pretty convinced that some shopping questions are inherently on-topic here. Some stuff you need for travel is hard to find in some places. Questions about where to get gear X in place Y should be OK. Stuff like price and brand comparisons would still be off-topic.

Answer (score -3):

Discuss criteria for suspension in the event of .... 'heated' discussions / trolling?

Comment: This is more a of a mod issue. SE is not a democracy :)

Comment: Suspended, one week ;)

Comment: Well I vote for democracy d-;

Answer (score -3):

Expat and immigration questions - do we want to include them or not?

Comment: This has been a longstanding "no" since the proposal and through the beta. I think it's a waste of limited time resources to bring it up again.

Answer (score -3):

What is good "subjective" and bad "subjective"?